# Is there a site where you can connect with individuals willing to go to local sources & research for you?

Tags: locating-records

I need info from the Wyoming Boys School from 1937 re: my father.  I've tried contacting the school inquiring if they have records that can be accessed from that period but I get no response.  Is there someone out there near the school who is willing to go there and see?  Or is there a site that would list info on the boys there in that year?

Answer (score 4):

The classic answer to this was [Random Acts of Genealogical Kindness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_Acts_of_Genealogical_Kindness) but alas the site is not currently operating.  [The RAOGK Wiki](http://raogk.wikia.com/wiki/Random_Acts_of_Genealogical_Kindness_Wiki) offers an alternative, as does [Mocavo Karma.](http://www.mocavo.com/karma)

I haven't used any of these sites myself, so can't vouch for them.

Answer (score 4):

For any 20th century records, the first question I have is whether or not the records are closed because of privacy concerns.  This seems very likely in the case of an institution like the [Wyoming Boys School](https://sites.google.com/a/wyo.gov/dfsweb/social-services/wyoming-boys-school); the records may be sealed by court order.  If this is not the case, then they might be available to a direct descendant like you.  However, I doubt that kind of record would be available to a random genealogical volunteer that happened to live in the area, the kind of volunteer who would list themselves on the sites ColeValleyGirl indicated.

For a similar case study, see the article [Skillbuilding: In Search of Criminal Records](http://www.bcgcertification.org/skillbuilders/skbld089.html) by Gene F. Williams, CG.

The Wyoming State Archives has a page on [Genealogical Resources](http://wyoarchives.state.wy.us/Archives/Genealogical.aspx) which says the archives holds some court records, but the individual courts retain the indexes.  Their site says:

> Juvenile Criminal cases are restricted by the courts. Please contact
>   the court in question about access. Information about incarceration at
>   the Wyoming Boys School, Wyoming Girls School and Wyoming Training
>   School are also restricted and we can neither confirm nor deny an
>   individual’s incarceration at any of these facilities. Please contact
>   the Department of Corrections for access to the records.

You've attempted to contact the institution directly and have had no answer.  Now what?

The FAQ on the [Department of Criminal Investigations](http://wyomingdci.wyo.gov/dci-criminal-justice-information-systems-section/criminal-records-section/criminal-history-checks)' website says:

> Q16. As a juvenile, what happens to my state criminal history when I reach the age of 18?
>
> When a juvenile reaches the age of majority (18), their Wyoming state
>   criminal history record is deleted unless they were convicted of a
>   misdemeanor and/or a felony as an adult. If a juvenile was convicted
>   of a crime(s) as an adult, then #15 would apply.

[Question #15 is about what records are expunged.]

There is a downloadable PDF available on that site: [CourtRecordsInformation.PDF](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=d3lvLmdvdnxkY2ktLS1wdWJsaWN8Z3g6NzFmYjQ5NGZiOWNiYzc0ZA)

Since you aren't in the area, it may be more efficient to hire a professional.  If so, be prepared to provide proof of your relationship, if that is needed (see Williams' article for the kind of documentation he was given by his client), and to give the professional whatever information you have about how you know your father was at the Wyoming Boys School in 1937, and any other information you may have about his criminal history, since it may have a bearing on whether his juvenile records were retained by the state or not.

Another possibility might be to consult a lawyer in the area, to ask if a judge could reopen any records which might survive.  (The ideal person to answer this question for you would be a genealogist who is also a lawyer.)

You could

- try the link in the sidebar to Williams' article marked "Find a Genealogist" to locate a Board-Certified Genealogist
- contact the county or state bar association to find a lawyer to help with court records
- post a separate question here on G&FH.SE about how to find and choose a professional genealogist.